# Are imperative verbs starting a command subordinating conjunctions?

Tags: syntax, verbs, syntax-trees, imperative

I have come across a syntax tree with a subordinate clause phrase (as opposed to just a sentence) whose left daughter is a verb in the imperative, e.g. *Wash your laundry tonight.*

I have read this [post](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6182/languages-with-subordinate-imperatives) and also these resources which define a subordinate conjunction: [1](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subordinateconjunction.htm), [2](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/grammar_subordinate.html), and [3](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000377.htm), but none of them said an imperative verb could be a subordinate conjunction.

Last, I also searched several thousand parsed trees but not a single left daughter was a verb to the subordinate clause phrase.

My conclusion is that it's a tagger mistake.

Edit: Here is the utterance for context

*Review your homework for 30 minutes and make sure it is complete.*

In the tree, *review* is assigned the part-of-speech label for a subordinating conjunction, being the left daughter to that subordinating clause.

Comment: Can you provide the whole sentence to give us some context?

Comment: Probably it is a tagger mistake; somebody musta defined a subordinate clause as one lacking a subject NP. English speakers do use bald subordinate clauses as single utterances, after all.

Comment: It's a tagger mistake. *and* isn't a subordinating conjunction, but rather we're dealing with coordination.

Comment: @ThomasGross  I was not referring not to *and* but to *review* being labeled as a subordinating conjunction.  Could you explain how a trained tagger could make this mistake (I would accept that as an answer)?  I'm assuming the tagger is some kind of HMM/CRF trained on a lot of annotated data.  How could it label a verb as IN if that never occurs in the training set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by user3898238 in his comment to mine, I try to provide an answer:
The verb *review* is, wrongly, labeled as a subordinating conjunction for the possible reason that in English conjunctions precede the clause they head. Since a subordinating conjunction is absent, the program simply chooses the next available option, i.e. the initial word.

My explanation for the program apparently seeing a subordinating structure, instead of a coordinating one, would be that the presence of the coordinating conjunction *and* forces a two-clause analysis. And many computer linguists (i.e. the people who build taggers, etc.) view coordination as akin to subordination (cf. the treatment of coordination in [MTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meaning-Text_Theory)).

According to my personal experience, computer "linguists" make terrible linguists.